# How to capture entire scrolling <div> into an image

Tags: java, selenium

I am currently using "Selenium" to develop web auotomation scripts in Java. I am trying to find a way to capture entire scrolling DIV(html) into an image. Any quick solution ??

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZduC.png

Comment: screen capture? do you want a picture?

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I am trying to find a way to capture entire scrolling div into an image. Example: h t t p : // i.imgur.com/AZduC.png

Answer (score 0):

When you say you want the  content, do you mean the HTML or just the text on the screen? If its the text, you can use an XPATH like `selenium.getText(//div[@id='theDiv'])`. If its the HTML, you could evaluate JavaScript on the page to the the innerHTML, like this:

```
selenium.getEval("this.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().document.getElementById('theDiv').innerHTML")
```

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I am trying to find a way to capture entire scrolling div into an image.

Example: h t t p ://i.imgur.com/AZduC.png

Answer (score 0):

You can get a screenshot of the whole page with Selenium's captureEntirePageScreenshot(String imageFileURLToWrite).

In principal it should be possible to post process the image to extract just the DIV. You'd need to work out the exact pixel bounds of the DIV, which would probably require the use of getEval() to run some JavaScript on the client.

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty easy.

1. You take screenshot from the browser window
2. You take location X and Y of the Div
3. You take size of the Div: Width and Length
4. Create Bitmap with the same size and copy subimage using info from 2 and 3 from screenshot taken in step 1.

If you want I can give you code from C#. But its not so hard and I believe you can code it by your own hands.